# How to join 2 query results prometheus

Tags: grafana, promql

I'm trying to query a Prometheus database to determine how many customers have recorded data for one metric with a specific label filter, but not another metric with a different label filter. I.e. all the customer_id's that show up in

`sum(usage{usage_type="type_b"}) by (customer_id)`

but not in

`count(service_plan{plan_type=~".*plan_b.*"}) by (customer_id)`

I could run each and just mash them together outside Prometheus, but I want to do this either in a single query in Prometheus, or with some fancy transformation tricks in Grafana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `unless` operator - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators). The following query should return customer ids, which exist in the first query and are missing in the second query:

```
sum(usage{usage_type="type_b"}) by (customer_id)
  unless
count(service_plan{plan_type=~".*plan_b.*"}) by (customer_id)
```